# TypeScript - compile errors in vs.net?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

In vs.net in an MVC4 project, is it possible to make your project build stop incase your typescript files contains errors?

Currently I can see errors from the active file I'm editing, but they don't break the build so to say.
I'd like to have true build errors incase some typescript file doesn't compile correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the compiler using the Before Build target, you'll get errors as part of your build:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc&quot; @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" />
  </Target>
```

You really only need to point at your "top level" file (such as app.ts) and it will walk all of the dependencies, so you can just set the build action to TypeScriptCompile on for that file alone (properties window).